# How can I get the parameter data from previous post, that is not shown in the url

Tags: jquery, ajax, combobox

In a combobox, I post a parameter to the url using AJAX in Jquery with below script:

```
$('#plant').change(function(e2){
$('#location').html('<img src="02_files/01_images/loading.gif">');
    var plant = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "03_themepage/sfer/otherforms/z161_combobox_action.php",
        data: "plant="+plant,
        success: function(data){
            $('#location').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

When I run the script, after selecting the option from this combobox, in the url, parameter 'plant' is not shown. Actually the url not changed at all.

Meanwhile, I need the data from the first combobox (as per selected), to be included in the next combobox.

```
$('#location').change(function(e3){
$('#maingroup').html('<img src="02_files/01_images/loading.gif">');
    var location = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "03_themepage/sfer/otherforms/z161_combobox_action.php",
        data: "plant="+plant+"&location="+location, //plant data taken from previous url post
        success: function(data){
            $('#maingroup').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Both data will be required for the last combobox.

My question is, how can I get the parameter data from the 1st combobox to be included in the 2nd combobox, since it is not shown in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax not change the url, but the request is done without refreshing the page, and you can see it through network tab. To take the first combo box value which is `plant` variable, declare plant variable in global state like so :

```
// global declaration, can be accessed inside 2nd handler as well
var plant;

$('#plant').change(function(e2){
 $('#location').html('<img src="02_files/01_images/loading.gif">');
    plant = $(this).val(); // <---- here assign the post value(selected value)
    .....
    .....
});
```

Then inside second combo box, just call those variable like you did.